# pip driver is installed but module not found

Tags: python, cassandra, pip, cassandra-driver

I am trying to install cassandra driver for my python here

[image: Install Driver]

And this is my code in the python

[image]
[image]

However i still get an error saying no module name found 'cassandra'

Answer (score 0):

Do you use anaconda? If yes, before the "pip install cassandra-driver" command line.
Do "activate base", if you are using the base environment.

Comment: I am using spyder, but I think it's part of anaconda. When I tried to run command "activate base" it says command not recognize

Comment: Ok, go to \Anaconda3\Scripts folder with command line (open terminal) : "cd <your_path>", then do "activate base" and run pip command.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is still the same :(